# C#: Can I cast an explicit delegate to an Action delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

Given:

```
delegate void Explicit();
```

Can I:

```
public void Test(Explicit d)
{
    Action a;
    a = d; // ????
}
```

I have a scenario where I need to overload a constructor that has:

```
public MyClass(Expression<Action> a) {}
```

but the following overload is ambiguous:

```
public MyClass(Action a) {}
```

I figured using an explicit delegate would resolve the ambiguity but I need to cast that explicit delegate to an action in order to leverage the existing code.

Comment: Note that this isn't an ambiguity issue. Even if you didn't have an overloaded constructor, it wouldn't let you pass an instance of `Explicit` to an argument of type `Action`, because they're not directly compatible. You'd still need a conversion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Action a = new Action(d);
```

Comment: While this works, it should be noted that it actually creates a new delegate instance which references `d.Invoke`. If you keep doing this, the delegate chain will grow, and every invocation of such delegate will result in a chain of virtual `Invoke` calls, so there is a certain perf hit (not that it's likely that you run into this problem in practice).

Answer (score 9):

No you cannot cast different delegate types with matching signatures between each other.  You must create a new delegate / lambda expression of the target type and forward into the original one.

Comment: This feature was requested way back in 2006 and was rejected.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=159810

Comment: @alex Dead link 404

Answer (score 4):

You can also specify the Invoke method to create the new Action delegate

```
Action a = new Action(d.Invoke);
```